# Ternary shorthand for foo ? foo : bar

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, shorthand

I realized I am using the ternary operator most of the time as following:

`foo ? foo : bar;`

This becomes cumbersome, as the variable length gets quite long, e. g.

`appModel.settings.notifications ? appModel.settings.notifications : {};`

Is there any shorthand or more elegant way of doing this?
Perhaps `ES6` or `ES7`?

Comment: `appModel.settings.notifications || {}`

Comment: Maybe `appModel.settings.notifications || {}`

Comment: `var a = appModel.settings.notifications; a ? a : {};`, Short enough?

Comment: What are you doing with the result of the expression?

Comment: You don't need ternary for such simple case as `foo ? foo : bar`. [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) operator does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it like this :

```
var foo = foo || {};
appModel.settings.notifications = appModel.settings.notifications || {};
```

you can also cumulate

```
options = default.options || foo.options || bar.options || { foo:'bar'};
```

Comment: Yep, that is the "nice" behaviour of [JS logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), which are evaluated from left to right. But this is quite obscure unfortunately for JS beginners…

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use non-bitwise boolean operators:

```
foo || bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

When checking for nullish values we can now use the [Logical Nullish Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment):

```
foo ??= bar
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480993/when-should-i-use-nullish-coalescing-vs-logical-or) for difference between nullish and falsy.

```js
//these statements are the same for nullish values (null and undefined):

//falsy check
foo = foo ? foo : bar;

//falsy check
foo = foo || bar;

//nullish check
foo ??= bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `in` here as well, may be a bit more Human friendly, and this won't ever block.

```
 notifications in appModel.settings || {}
```